# Correctly calculating the size of an array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, sizeof, pointer-arithmetic

```
int a[3][3] = { {8,7,6},{5,4,3},{2,1,0} };
printf("sizeof(a[1]+1): %zu\n", sizeof(a[1]+1));
printf("sizeof(a+1): %zu\n", sizeof(a+1));
```

i'm trying to figure out why does the program output is:

```
sizeof(a[1]+1): 8

sizeof(a+1): 8
```

i expected the output to be

```
sizeof(a[1]+1): 24  //sizeof(a[1]) + sizeof(a[1]) (12 + 12)

sizeof(a+1): 72     //sizeof(a) + sizeof(a) (36 + 36)
```

Comment: You're getting back the size of a pointer in both expressions. But it isn't clear to me what size you're actually trying to get, or why you think that adding 1 to the expression will double its size.

Comment: whan you use `a+1` you use `a` as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

In this expression `a[1]+1` there is used the pointer arithmetic.

The sub-expression `a[1]` having the array type `int[3]` is implicitly converted to pointer to the array element type that is to pointer of the type `int *`. So the whole expression has the type `int *`. And this call of `printf`

```
printf("sizeof(a[1]+1): %zu\n", sizeof(a[1]+1));
```

outputs the size of a pointer of the type `int *`.

In this expression `a+1` where there is also used the pointer arithmetic the array designator `a` having the array type `int[3][3]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its element type `int ( * )[3]`. And the full expression has this type.

So this call of `printf`

```
printf("sizeof(a+1): %zu\n", sizeof(a+1));
```

also outputs the size of a pointer.

If you need to get the size of the whole array you can write

```
printf("sizeof(a): %zu\n", sizeof(a));
```

If you want to output the size of its elements you can write

```
printf("sizeof(a[0]): %zu\n", sizeof(a[0]));
```

or

```
printf("sizeof(*a): %zu\n", sizeof(*a));
```

It seems you do not understand the pointer arithmetic as for example in this your statement

```
sizeof(a+1): 72     //sizeof(a) + sizeof(a) (36 + 36)
```

This expression

```
sizeof(a+1)
```

is not the same as the expression `suzeof( a ) + sizeof( a )`.

The compiler determines the type of the expression `a + 1` that has the type `int ( * )[3]` as pointed above and yields the size of an object of this type.

I think this quote from the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators) will be useful for you

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

So for example `sizeof( a )` yields the size of the whole array. In this expression the array designator does not implicitly converted to pointer to the array element type.

However if you will write instead `sizeof( a + 0 )` then in this expression `a + 0` the array designator will be converted to pointer to the array element type and the operator `sizeof` yields the size of pointer.